# How to solve double curly brackets issue when using Vue + Django template language?

Tags: python, django, vuejs2

I am using [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/) and would like to use Vue on my project. One main problem I encountered is `{{...}}` syntax. My Vue data is not rendered at all.

```
<div id="app">{{ message }} // This is just empty on my page </div>
```

And I am just using this basic Vue script:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Would the [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) template tag work for you? eg: `<div id="app">{% verbatim %}{{ message }}{% endverbatim %}`...

Comment: That works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What glenfant said is easy, but this is even easier.

```
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['{', '}'],
    el: '#app',
    data: { message: 'Hello Vue!' },
})
```

That’s all: you configure Vue with the tag it should use to work. :) I use just one brace – `{…}` – but you can use doubled square brackets, too: `[[` and `]]`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `verbatim` template tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

```
<div id="app">{% verbatim %}{{ message }}{% endverbatim %}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your base template, you can add this line:

```
 <script>Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'];</script>
```

Then you will able to use `%{...}`  for Vue, `{{...}}` for django.