# Django & Vue.js: Pass a json API result to a django template tag

Tags: vue.js, django-templates

I have a json response and I want to pass it to a custom django template tag. Normally that should be `{% template_tag django_var %}`

Since Vue.js and Django use the same `{{ obj }}` syntax I instructed Vue to use the delimiters `[[ obj ]]` instead.

Now I want to achieve something like: `{% template_tag [[ vue.ajax.var ]] %}`
also plain `{% template_tag vue.ajax.var %}` does not work.

The variable exists, I can interpolate it w/o problems like `[[ vue.ajax.var ]]`

How to pass the string to the django template tag?

**Appendix:**

`{% template_tag {% verbatim %} [[ vue.ajax.var ]] {% endverbatim %} %}` does NOT work, of course.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024817/how-to-solve-double-curly-brackets-issue-when-using-vue-django-template-langua)

Comment: verbatim does not work inside a `{% template tag %}` declaration. Not working Amr.

Comment: I think what you want is pretty impossible, since django template is already rendered at server side (before delivered to browser), and this template tag does not knows anything about vuejs data attribute, since vuejs renders template in client's browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js in Django Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125278/vue-js-in-django-templates)