# Vue.js in Django Templates

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-templates

I am trying to use Vue.js in Django templates. One such template is the following:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myApp">
        <span>Hello [[ message ]]</span>
        <div id="map"></map>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://v1.vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I changed Vue's interpolation delimiters to **[[ ]]** to avoid conflict with Django. My `script.js` looks as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#myApp',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data: {
            message: 'Hello, world!'
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the HTML rendered contains `[[ message ]]`. Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: What version of vue are you using?

Comment: https://v1.vuejs.org/js/vue.js v1.0.28

Comment: Quite surprisingly, `v-text="message"` directive works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the per [docs](https://v1.vuejs.org/api/#delimiters) of Vue v1.0 say:

```
// ES6 template string style
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}']
```

So, in your example change to:

```
$(function() {
    Vue.config.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#myApp',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello, world!'
        }
    });
});
```

It is strongly recomended, though, to use the new version of Vue (version 2) in order to be up-to-date!

Comment: Works. Didn't work when I tried it in the console though, perhaps because Vue needs all the config because it interpolates. By the way, how can I speed up the interpolation when the page is first loaded?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://v1.vuejs.org/api/#Global-Config) **again** say: *`Vue.config` is an object containing Vue’s global configurations. You can modify its properties listed below **before** bootstrapping your application*. As for your other question, it is prefered to ask a new question for that!

Answer (score 4):

Django has builtin functionality to skip interpreting template using [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim)

```
<div id="myApp">
    {% verbatim %}
       {{ value_from_vue }}
    {% endverbatim %}
    {{ value_from_django }}
</div>

<script>
    var myApp = new Vue({
        el: '#myApp',
        data: {
            value_from_vue: "hello from vue"
        }
    })
</script>
```

Anything goes inside verbatim won't be interpreted by the django template engine. This functionality also useful for other (if any) Javascript libraries when they don't provide delimiter option.

However, if configuring delimiter is preferred:

for latest **Vue (version 2+)**, put the config inside the vue instance just like in the question.

```
$(function() {
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#myApp',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data: {
            message: 'Hello, world!'
        }
    });
});
```

for **Version 1 of Vue**, use just like the answer by nik_m

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];
```